# Kivy - Why Label does not update?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change a text of a label but I can't do it, I can see it changing on the shell but not on the UI. I even directly change the text of the label by referencing its id but still its not updating. Anyone knows how to do this?

```
class MainApp(Screen, EventDispatcher):
title = "Top 10 Plays of 2015"

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(MainApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def change_curr_title(self, title, *args):
    self.title = title
    self.ids.lblTitle.text = self.title
    print(self.ids.lblTitle.text)
pass

class OtherVideos(BoxLayout, EventDispatcher):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OtherVideos,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.loadVideos()

def loadVideos(self):
    self.clear_widgets()
    con = MongoClient()
    db = con.nba
    vids = db.videos.find()

    vidnum = 1
    for filename in vids:
        myid = "vid" + str(vidnum)
        getfilename = filename['filename']

        button = Button(id=myid,
                      text=getfilename,
                      color=[0,0.7,1,1],
                      bold=1)
        button.bind(on_release=partial(self.change_Title, getfilename))
        self.add_widget(button)
        vidnum += 1

def change_Title(self, title, *args):
    main = MainApp()
    main.change_curr_title(title)
```

This is the construction of my kivy:

```
<MainApp>:
    ....
    BoxLayout:
    ....
        BoxLayout:
        ....some widgets
        BoxLayout:
            OtherVideos:
                ...this is where the buttons are generated...
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    id: lblTitle
                    text: root.title
```

Is there anyway to upload my whole code on this? like the file itself, so you guys can look at it.

EDIT: I can easily update the label when I'm making a new method like this without a parameter and binding it to a button through kivy

```
def update_label(self):
    self.ids.lblTitle.text = "New Title"
```

I don't know why buttons with events created dynamically doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
def change_Title(self, title, *args):
    main = MainApp()  # !
    main.change_curr_title(title)
```

you are creating a new object of screen (`MainApp`), which isn't connected to anything. To make it work, `main` should link to the existing instance of `MainApp` screen.

The `OtherVideos` box layout needs to have a reference to it, preferably in kv file.

---

**Edit**

In order to create a link from `MainApp` to `OtherVideos`, create an `ObjectProperty`:

```
class OtherVideos(BoxLayout):

    main = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OtherVideos,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loadVideos()
    ...
```

which will be populated in kv file:

```
OtherVideos:
    main: root
    ...this is where the buttons are generated...
```

Then, in the `change_Title` function, use this reference:

```
def change_Title(self, title, *args):    
    self.main.change_curr_title(title)
```

Comment: Thanks~ let me upload the file.

Comment: @KPA Please edit your question showing where the `OtherVideos` is placed in kv file - for future readers.

Comment: Done. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :D

Comment: btw, can you explain to me where did you get that main and root in the OtherVideos layout

Comment: @KPA `root` is kv language specific variable, and always points to the first widget of a rule. `main` is an ObjectProperty (you can pick any name) bound to the `root`, what means if root changes, `main` also will change.